# Sonarqube Branch does not exist on server

Tags: sonarqube

When I try to analyze my project using sonar-scanner, the scan fails with the following error message:

```
Caused by: Branch does not exist on server: develop
```

Apparently, this only happens when it analyzes a Pull Request from GitHub. I could reproduce the error, when I add the following configuration to `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.branch.name = source-branch
sonar.branch.target = target-branch
```

What could be the cause for this problem?

Comment: Does `target-branch` actually exist in your project in SonarQube as a long-lived branch?

Comment: Yes, it exists. It actually worked until recently. I have metrics on that branch already.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam [This](https://github.com/Flux-Coordinator/flux-frontend/pull/9) is the pull request. [This](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=flux-frontend%3Adevelop) is the project on Sonarcloud.

Comment: Since `develop` _is_ your master branch and the master will be targeted by default, please try omitting `sonar.branch.target` & update here.

Comment: I don't use `sonar.branch.target`. I just could reproduce the error with that. If I understand correctly, this should resolve itself if I add develop as a long-living branch to the [project](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=flux-frontend) analyzing the master branch? I don't know why the feature branch is listed as a short-living branch of the real master branch, but the develop branch is listed as it's own project.

Comment: I have deleted the project on Sonarcloud that analyzes the develop branch. I think if I putt all branches under one project, it might help mitigate this problem. Now the thing is that my develop branch doesn't get recognized on SonarCloud. The regex for long-living-branches is like this: `(develop)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting my Sonar project that was watching the `develop` branch. Then I added the `develop` branch as a long-living branch to the Sonar project analyzing the `master` branch. Before, I had a Sonar project for each long-living branch, because I was using the `branches` property in `travis.yml` ([which is getting deprecated now](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/sonarcloud/#Depreated-features)).

To add a new branch to Sonarqube you need to add the `sonar.branch.name` property with the name of the desired branch to the `sonar-project.properties` file. E.g.: `sonar.branch.name=develop`

Then you run `sonar-scanner` and your branch will be available inside the Sonar-Project.*

* Make sure to check if the Regex for long-living branches is appropriate to your new branch on Sonarqube. You can't change a long-living branch to a short-living branch or vice-versa after the branch is added to Sonarqube.

The result is that I have only one project on Sonarqube now that watches all my branches. It's a lot cleaner and works better.

[More information on the branch plugin.](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Branch+Plugin)

Comment: How did you add `develop` as a long-lived branch? I have not been able to do this by editing the RegEx on the "Branches & Pull Requests" section to `(master|develop).*`

Comment: I am not working with Sonarqube at the moment, but is it maybe because of the `.` before the `*`? Just guessing... I also had some problems until I got it right, IIRC.